# ¿Cómo coincidir el mismo campo en 2 tablas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, join

Tengo 2 tablas, una para registro de usuarios  y otra de suscripciones de los mismos. En ambas se recoge el campo 'email'. 
La idea es cruzar el email de una tabla con el correo de la otra para comprobar que coincidan. Si coinciden, el usario tendrá acceso al contenido.
 Soy nueva en MYSQL, miré turoriales pero no me aclaro cómo hacerlo, creo que es con JOIN? hay que crear otra tabla a parte? crear un nuevo campo de ID?

TABLAS: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,correo FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$correo = $row["correo"];

$sql2 = "SELECT email,status FROM subscriptions WHERE status = 'Active'";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
$row2= $result2->fetch_assoc();
$status = $row2["status"];
$email = $row2["email"];

//  SI COINCIDEN LOS EMAILS ,SI EL USUARIO ES ACTIVO Y SI HAY SESION
if(($correo == $email) && ($status = 'Active') && isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])) { ?>

            MOSTRAR CONTENIDO HTML

        <?php } 

        else { ?>

             OTRO CONTENIDO


       <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Es muy fácil y ahí no se ve el intento de tu Join, intenta hacer el Join por ti mismo y si no te sale vienes con dudas más concretas

Comment: No sé si es correcto ni qué obtengo con esto?     SELECT subscriptions.email, usuarios.correo, 
FROM subscriptions
INNER JOIN usuarios ON subscriptions.email=usuarios.correo;

Comment: Inténtalo, no pierdes nada y tu información no se alterará y ves si es lo que buscas, sino como repito, haces una pregunta más específica

Comment: Aparte del asunto del `JOIN` me parece un tipo de comprobación *extraño* el que intentas implementar aquí. Eso de mantener dos correos para luego compararlos y dar acceso a un cierto contenido es muy extraño... En ese caso lo normal sería tener una columna numérica en la tabla `usuarios` que indique un `nivel` o un `tipo_usuario` y en base al nivel o al tipo dar acceso al contenido.

Answer (score 0):

El método de recorrer 2 consultas podría funcionar pero no sería lo más óptimo como solución.

Lo que necesitas en este caso es hacer un [INNER JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) de dos tablas. Puedes obtener los registros que tengan el mismo correo de la siguiente manera:

```sql
SELECT usuarios.correo, subscriptions.status
FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN subscriptions
ON usuarios.correo = subscriptions.email
WHERE subscriptions.status = 'Active';
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias funcionó!

Comment: @MamenMaria No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que otras personas puedan ver la solución. Gracias.